# Base methods Java for a Google Map fragment without a layout Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new at Android and i'm having quite a headache. First i created all the layouts for my App and now i started to make the methods.

Following the Google Guideline [Hello Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/), the problem is that this method is an activity with your own layout, however the fragment that i'm using that holds the map, it's not.

When i don't use a "class" to my fragment in XML, it shows the map. But when i do and try to use this method [Hello Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/), it doesn't show anything.

Here's the xml file containing the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_menu"
tools:context=".MenuActivity">


<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_map"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Digite o Local"
    />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_map"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_map"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_map"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    class="com.example.RF.MyApp.MapFragment" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the Java code that i was trying to use, it's very bad haha

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

 View myView;
public MapFragment(){

    // Required empty public constructor
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    myView=relativeLayout;


    return myView;
}


public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
}
```

If somebody has a solution, please help me. Thanks! 
;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a static Fragment, I would use a FrameLayout and dynamically add the Fragment in the Activity code.

As for creating a Map Fragment class that doesn't need a layout xml, just have the Fragment extend SupportMapFragment.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment 
                       implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marker;


    public MyMapFragment () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                //remove previously placed Marker
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much! About adding dynamically using FrameLayout, are you talking about Material Design? I'm very new at this and i was following a book, but anyways, i have a deadline and i will use this for now. But if you have some urls or references that you want to share, i would appreciate a lot.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My code from project

```
    MainActivity extends Activity
    {

   OnCreateBundle()
  {
    CheckGoogleMap();
  }

    }
         private void CheckGoogleMap()
            {

                try {
                    if (googleMap == null) {
                        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                                findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

                    }

                    UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
                    uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);
                    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);


                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Remove class reference from XMl..

Comment: That's the problem, my fragment it's not an Activity and doesn't have a layout. If i don't put the reference, it will be able to go to a java code ?

Comment: No, for this reference will work see below answer given another person. :)